# Open with Neovim files that were encrypted with Vim

Tags: neovim, encryption

It seems I cannot open with Neovim the files I have encrypted with Vim.
Neovim just open the files without decrypting them, displaying all those gibberish character sequence.

Is it considered normal ? Is there a way around, or is it a bug ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All support for `cryptmethod` was removed in [`85338fe`](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/commit/85338fe1d5a56f82546e16c305c2048c081771e0). See the linked pull requests for (lengthy) discussions about it. There is no way to open these files with Neovim. You will need to use Vim.